# Filtering a javascript array object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load a json file to a javascript object whith jquery.
I get an array object (each row is a json object).
[image]

Currently, I display javascript object content to a html table with a for on each row of the obect.
Is it possible to directly filter my javascript array object depending on the columns conditions and not with a for command again?
Thanks a lot.
Theo.

Comment: Yes/Probably: Filter a js array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter But sounds more like you want to "filter" the html rows after you've rendered them, in which case: https://api.jquery.com/filter/ Perhaps you could be a little more specific than just "is it possible".

Answer (score 0):

---

probably this can help you with little change

```
const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
```

Comment: Thanks. After researches, I found this type of answer.